RecycleView displays the size of the array but do not display the text in the items? How can I fix this ? I am really desperated :((
The recycleView does receive the data from the firestore and the size of the arrays , but the TextView is blank
Here is the model code:
public class Subscription {
    public   String name;
    public   String frequency;
    public Date startDate;
    public String reminder;
    public float cost;
    public   String email;
    public   String password;
    public Subscription (){

    }

    public Subscription(String name, String frequency, Date startDate, String reminder, float cost, String email, String password)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.frequency = frequency;
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.reminder = reminder;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getSubName() {return name;}
    public String getFrequency() {return frequency;}
    public Date getStartDate() {return startDate;}
    public String getReminder() {return reminder;}
    public float getCost() {return cost;}
    public String getEmail() {return email;}
    public String getPassword() {return password;}
}

Here is Adapter class:
public class SubAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SubAdapter.Subholder> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Subscription> subscriptions;

    public SubAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Subscription> subscriptions) {
        this.context = context;
        this.subscriptions = subscriptions;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SubAdapter.Subholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.mainviewlist,parent ,false);

        return new Subholder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SubAdapter.Subholder holder, int position) {

        Subscription subs = subscriptions.get(position);

        holder.subName.setText(subs.getSubName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return subscriptions.size();
    }

    public  static  class Subholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView subName;
        public Subholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            subName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.MVL_text);
        }
    }
}

And here is the MainActivity :
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button AddSub = null;
    FirebaseFirestore subDB;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<Subscription> Subarraylist;

    SubAdapter subAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });


        AddSub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AM_AddSubBtn);
        AddSub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddSubscriptionActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        subDB = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.MA_recycleView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        Subarraylist = new ArrayList<Subscription>();
        subAdapter = new SubAdapter(MainActivity.this , Subarraylist );
        recyclerView.setAdapter(subAdapter);
        Eventchangelistener();


    }

    private void Eventchangelistener() {
        FirebaseAuth tempAuth;
        tempAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser userGet = tempAuth.getCurrentUser();
        assert userGet != null;
        String userEmail = userGet.getEmail();
        subDB.collection("subscriptions").document(userEmail).collection("subscriptions").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                if(error != null){
                    Log.e("Error" ,error.getMessage());
                    return;
                }
                Subarraylist.clear();
                for(DocumentChange dc : value.getDocumentChanges()){
                    if(dc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){
                        Subarraylist.add(dc.getDocument().toObject(Subscription.class));
                    }
                    subAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
    }

And here is the picture what the problem:
enter image description here
I already try many methods but nothing works. Hope you guys can give me some advices, I really appriciate that.

Looks like the problem is in R.layout.mainviewlist, can you show the code?

@GHH 
 Here is the XML , I don't see any error in this :(((

try to change 'layout_widthintomatch_parentand gravity tocenter`.

Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please respond using @AlexMamo

@AlexMamo Thank you so much, I just found the solution when I saw the word database structure, It's because the variable in the model class is different in the Firestore

I thought about that. That's why I asked for a screenshot. Good to hear that you made it work.
